Microsoft Exchange 2019 Search not indexing new content
End of last year I upgraded Exchange Server 2016 to 2019. Everything was working after that. Following the upgrade, Exchange stopped indexing new content. Search is not returning new messages.
One error is that the Microsoft Exchange Search Host Controller service cannot start.
I am running exchange 2019 CU13 with all the latest hotfixes applied.
Attempting to reinstall Search Foundation fails.
Attempting to install CU14 fails on Search Foundation.
Below is the error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
            if ($RoleProductPlatform -eq "amd64")
            {
                try
                {
                    # Need to configure the ETL traces before the fast service is installed. This will ensure that when the service comes up
                    # it will have the necessary trace session setting available to read from the registry
                    $fastPerfEtlTraceFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $RoleBinPath -ChildPath "\Search\Ceres\Diagnostics\ETLTraces"
                    $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\16.0\Search\Diagnostics\Tracing'
                    if(-not(Test-Path -Path $fastPerfEtlTraceFolderPath))
                    {
                        $null = New-Item $fastPerfEtlTraceFolderPath -Type 'Directory' -Force 
                    }
                    
                    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath))
                    {
                        $null = New-Item -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Force
                    }
                    
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'TracingPath' -PropertyType 'string' -Value $fastPerfEtlTraceFolderPath -Force
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'TracingFileName' -PropertyType 'string' -Value 'DocumentProcessingTrace' -Force
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'DocumentParserSuccessLogMessage' -PropertyType 'Dword' -Value 1 -Force
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'DocumentParserLoggingNoInitialisation' -PropertyType 'Dword' -Value 1 -Force
                    
                    # Max trace folder size 50 * 100 = 5GB
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'MaxTraceFileSize' -PropertyType 'Dword' -Value 50 -Force
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'MaxTraceFileCount' -PropertyType 'Dword' -Value 100 -Force
                    
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'UseGeneralSwitch' -PropertyType 'Dword' -Value 1 -Force
                    $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $fastDiagnosticTracingRegKeyPath -Name 'GeneralSwitch' -PropertyType 'Dword' -Value 0 -Force
                }
                catch
                {
                    # ETl tracing is not critical. Info only log
                    Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Info ("An exception ocurred while trying to Configure the FAST ETL traces. Exception: " + $_.Exception.Message);
                }
 
                try
                {
                    $fastFusionRegKeyPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\16.0\Search\FlightControl' 
 
                    if (Test-Path -Path $fastFusionRegKeyPath)
                    {
                        Remove-ItemProperty -Path $fastFusionRegKeyPath -Name 'fusion_new_enabled' -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                        Remove-ItemProperty -Path $fastFusionRegKeyPath -Name 'fusion_old_enabled' -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                        Remove-ItemProperty -Path $fastFusionRegKeyPath -Name 'fusion_compare_outputs' -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    # Removing new fusion keys is not critical. Info only log
                    Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Info ("An exception ocurred while trying to remove the fast new fusion reg keys. Exception: " + $_.Exception.Message);
                }
                
                $fastInstallConfigPath = Join-Path -Path $RoleBinPath -ChildPath "Search\Ceres\Installer";
                $command = Join-Path -Path $fastInstallConfigPath -ChildPath "InstallConfig.ps1";
                $dataFolderPath = Join-Path -Path $RoleBinPath -ChildPath "Search\Ceres\HostController\Data";
 
                # Remove previous SearchFoundation configuration
                &$command -action u -silent;
                try
                {
                    if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($dataFolderPath))
                    {
                        [System.IO.Directory]::Delete($dataFolderPath, $true);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    $deleteErrorMsg = "Failure cleaning up SearchFoundation Data folder. - " + $dataFolderPath + " - " + $_.Exception.Message;
                    Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Error $deleteErrorMsg;
                }
 
                # Re-add the SearchFoundation configuration
                try
                {
                    # the BasePort value MUST be kept in sync with dev\Search\src\OperatorSchema\SearchConfig.cs
                    &$command -action i -baseport 3800 -dataFolder $dataFolderPath -silent;
                }
                catch
                {
                    $errorMsg = "Failure configuring SearchFoundation through installconfig.ps1 - " + $_.Exception.Message;
                    Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Error $errorMsg;
                    
                    # Clean up the failed configuration attempt.
                    &$command -action u -silent;
                    try
                    {
                        if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($dataFolderPath))
                        {
                            [System.IO.Directory]::Delete($dataFolderPath, $true);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        $deleteErrorMsg = "Failure cleaning up SearchFoundation Data folder. - " + $dataFolderPath + " - " + $_.Exception.Message;
                        Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Error $deleteErrorMsg;
                    }
                }
                
                # Set the PowerShell Snap-in's public key tokens
                try
                {
                    $PowerShellSnapinsPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\";
                    $FastSnapinNames = @("EnginePSSnapin", "HostControllerPSSnapIn", "InteractionEnginePSSnapIn", "JunoPSSnapin", "SearchCorePSSnapIn");
                    $officePublicKey = "71E9BCE111E9429C";
                    $exchangePublicKey = "31bf3856ad364e35";
                    foreach ($fastSnapinName in $FastSnapinNames)
                    {
                        $fastSnapinPath = $PowerShellSnapinsPath + $fastSnapinName;
                        $assemblyNameProperty = Get-ItemProperty -Path $fastSnapinPath -Name "AssemblyName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
                        if ($assemblyNameProperty -ne $null -and (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($assemblyNameProperty.AssemblyName)))
                        {
                            $newAssemblyName = $assemblyNameProperty.AssemblyName -ireplace ($officePublicKey, $exchangePublicKey);
                            Set-ItemProperty -Path $fastSnapinPath -Name "AssemblyName" -Value $newAssemblyName;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    # Info only log
                    Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Info ("An exception ocurred while configuring Search Foundation PowerShell Snapin. Exception: " + $_.Exception.Message);
                }
            }
        " was run: "System.Exception: Failure configuring SearchFoundation through installconfig.ps1 - Error occurred while configuring Search Foundation for Exchange.System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:3801/ceres/hostcontroller/nettcp. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0030724. TCP error code 10061: Nie można nawiązać połączenia, ponieważ komputer docelowy aktywnie go odmawia 127.0.0.1:3801.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Nie można nawiązać połączenia, ponieważ komputer docelowy aktywnie go odmawia 127.0.0.1:3801
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
 
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.WcfTypes.IHostController.GetHostInformation()
   at Microsoft.Ceres.Exchange.PostSetup.HostControllerManager.ConnectHost(Uri uri, Boolean secure, String userIdentity, Int16 timeoutInSeconds)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.Exchange.PostSetup.DeploymentManager.DeployAdminNode(String installDirectory, String localHostControllerNetTcpUrl, Int32 hostControllerPort)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.Exchange.PostSetup.DeploymentManager.Install(String installDirectory, String dataDirectoryPath, Int32 basePort, String logFile, Boolean singleNode, String systemName, Boolean attachedMode)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Boolean )
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.ThrowError(Exception exception, ErrorCategory errorCategory, Object target, String helpUrl)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Deployment.WriteExchangeSetupLog.InternalProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.<ProcessRecord>b__91_1()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.InvokeRetryableFunc(String funcName, Action func, Boolean terminatePipelineIfFailed)".

My event log is full of errors, over and over same two:
<Event xmlns=[**http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event**](http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event)>

**-** <System>

<Provider Name="**.NET Runtime** " />

<EventID Qualifiers="**0** ">**1026** </EventID>

<Level>**2** </Level>

<Task>**0** </Task>

<Keywords>**0x80000000000000** </Keywords>

<TimeCreated SystemTime="**2024-05-29T10:48:05.527644700Z** " />

<EventRecordID>**16693822** </EventRecordID>

<Channel>**Application** </Channel>

<Computer>**JAZZ.ad.infra.pl** </Computer>

<Security />

</System>

**-** <EventData>

<Data>**Aplikacja: hostcontrollerservice.exe Wersja architektury: v4.0.30319 Opis: proces został przerwany z powodu nieobsłużonego wyjątku. Informacje o wyjątku: System.TypeLoadException w Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.Controller.HostController..ctor(Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.Controller.HostControllerConfiguration, Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.Controller.DeploymentProperties) w Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.WcfServer.WcfService.InitializeHostController() w Microsoft.Ceres.HostController.WcfServer.WcfService.StartService() w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) w System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()** </Data>

</EventData>

</Event>

and
<Event xmlns=[**http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event**](http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event)>

**-** <System>

<Provider Name="**Application Error** " />

<EventID Qualifiers="**0** ">**1000** </EventID>

<Level>**2** </Level>

<Task>**100** </Task>

<Keywords>**0x80000000000000** </Keywords>

<TimeCreated SystemTime="**2024-05-29T10:48:05.598634900Z** " />

<EventRecordID>**16693823** </EventRecordID>

<Channel>**Application** </Channel>

<Computer>**JAZZ.ad.infra.pl** </Computer>

<Security />

</System>

**-** <EventData>

<Data>**hostcontrollerservice.exe** </Data>

<Data>**16.16.120.13** </Data>

<Data>**593aa481** </Data>

<Data>**KERNELBASE.dll** </Data>

<Data>**10.0.17763.5696** </Data>

<Data>**af5c8902** </Data>

<Data>**e0434352** </Data>

<Data>**0000000000041b29** </Data>

<Data>**52ec** </Data>

<Data>**01dab1b5af7ed116** </Data>

<Data>**C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Bin\Search\Ceres\HostController\hostcontrollerservice.exe** </Data>

<Data>**C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll** </Data>

<Data>**41221820-d1d3-4aae-a633-d54ba44f2b2a** </Data>

<Data />

<Data />

</EventData>

</Event>

I opened a support incident in Microsoft. After month of sending logs, script outputs, and other info the issue is not resolved.
